# Add millisecond to xslt format-time method

Tags: xml, xslt

There is an xml element called Qtime with timestamp. Qtime element format can be changed. Sample format for the Qtime element is shown below.

```
<Qtime>14:00:00.000Z</Qtime>
```

So, I used following xslt transformation to convert Qtime element.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-time(Qtime, '[H01]:[m01]:[s01]')" />
```

Now, I want to add millisecond to output element. And, I tried with the following command and it is not working.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-time(Qtime, '[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[S001]')" />
```

Is there any specific way to add milliseconds to format-time()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `f` for fractions of a second....

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-time(Qtime, '[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001]')" />
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-picture-string for a full list of possible "picture strings"